# Apple Push Notification - change from developer to production. What do to?

Tags: iphone, xcode, push

this week I will submit my App to the Appstore.
I have tested the push notification service with my developer- certificate on several devices. Everything works fine.

So what are the next steps?

1. Generate a Distribution Provisioning Profile and download to xcode.
2. Download the Production-Push-Certificate and generate a pem file.
3. use gateway.push.apple.com
4. ?

Thanks a lot!
Chris

Comment: That seems to be everything you've listed there, yes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Generate your production push certificate, then generate your distribution provisioning profile. When you want to send a push notification to a production user, send the JSON payload to gateway.push.apple.com using the production certificate.